# JQuery Mobile - Registration Form - The JS cannot call the php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have created a registration form, but the js file cannot call the php.

Are there anyone can give me some advise?

My question is when I click the submit button, there is no reaction. Do I have any mistakes? Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow">
<title>Tittle</title>
<script 
src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/registration.js"></script>
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js" 
type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/registration1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).on("mobileinit", function() {
       $.extend( $.mobile , {
       pageLoadErrorMessage: 'Either the page cannot be found or it cannot 
       be loaded.'
    });
 });
  $(document).on("pageinit","#page", function() {
    alert("pageinit is bound!");
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="main">
<div data-role="header">
<h1>Register</h1>
</div>
<form class="form" method="post" action="#">
    <label>Name :</label>
    <input type="text" name="dname" id="name">
    <label>Email :</label>
    <input type="text" name="demail" id="email">
    <label>Password :</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    <label>Confirm Password :</label>
    <input type="password" name="cpassword" id="cpassword">
<button type="button" name="register" id="register" 
class="btn">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
</div>
<div data-role="footer">
<h4>Footer</h4>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the JS

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#register").click(function () {
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var cpassword = $("#cpassword").val();
    if (name == '' || email == '' || password == '' || cpassword == '') {
        alert("Please fill all fields...!!!!!!");
    } else if ((password.length) < 8) {
        alert("Password should atleast 8 character in length...!!!!!!");
    } else if (!(password).match(cpassword)) {
        alert("Your passwords don't match. Try again?");
    } else {
        $.post("register.php", {
            name1: name,
            email1: email,
            password1: password
        }, function (data) {
            if (data == 'You have Successfully Registered.....') {
                  $("form")[0].reset();
                }
           alert(data);
         });
     }
 });
});
```

Below is the PHP

```
$hostname = "127.0.0.1";
$username = "root";
$password = "123456";
$connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) or die("Could 
not open connection to database");

$db = mysql_select_db("mydb", $connection); // Selecting Database.

$name=$_POST['name1']; 
$email=$_POST['email1'];
$password= sha1($_POST['password1']); 

$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL); 

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
echo "Invalid Email.......";
}

else{
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM registration WHERE email='$email'");
$data = mysql_num_rows($result);

if(($data)==0){
$query = mysql_query("insert into registration(name, email, password) values 
('$name', '$email', '$password')"); // Insert query

if($query){
echo "Successfully Registered";
}

else
{
echo "Error";
}
}

else{
echo "This email is already registered. Please try again";
}
}
mysql_close ($connection);
?>
```

Comment: There is **no more support** for `mysql_*` functions, they are [**officially deprecated**](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation), **no longer maintained** and [**removed**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#warning) in PHP 7.0.0. You should update your code with [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) to ensure the functionality of your project in the future.

Comment: You're using an ancient jQM version, use 1.4.5.

Answer (score 0):

Your `form action` is empty try changing `action="#"` to `action="register.php"`